# Tomcat start up expands JAVA symlink path to real absolute path

Tags: linux, java, tomcat

For setting up a path for binaries `symlinks` are the best way to go, however I encountered issues when the overlaying application uses this symlink sometimes goes for the exact absolute path.

For eg: Installing java in `/usr/lib/java1-8-345/` and then setting up a symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm` and set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm in tomcat setenv.sh`, when the tomcat starts up it uses the symlink but expands to the actual JVM source as:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/java1-8-345/jre
```

This will become an issue when new jdk version installs via yum update. I think this is purely on tomcat side. Is there any way we can fix that up without discarding yum update? I would like to keep yum update but wanted to make the symlink work as expected.

**Software versions**:
Java version: openjdk-1.8.0.345.b01-1.el7_9.x86_64
Tomcat Version: Tomcat/8.5.46

Comment: Is there really a problem? When Tomcat is started again after an update, doesn't it use the changed symlink?

Comment: @DonHolgo When we restart it uses the new expanded absolute path from the symlink but problem is when this happens in production, restarting manually is not ideal. The issue  will be some application might use say Java TZ class or so, these are picked up from the java standard library, so when the update happens via yum, it will update new version, and delete the old java version folder. So application runs into error that it cannot find that class in the java path, a restart will load new java path and will be file until the next java update happens in the background.